# How can I wget to traverse all symbolic links it comes across?

Tags: recursion, ftp, wget, lftp

## Issue

`wget` is not traversing symbolic links to directories to download the linked folders recursively.

## Backgroud

As per the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) of wget:

> By default, when retrieving FTP directories recursively and a symbolic link is encountered, the symbolic link is traversed and the pointed-to files are retrieved. Currently, Wget does not traverse symbolic links to directories to download them recursively, though this feature may be added in the future.

## Problem

I am trying to backup/mirror all of ftp://l5ftl01.larc.nasa.gov/ and there are thousands of symbolic/hardlinks to other folders and servers.

I tried using `wget -N -m ftp://l5ftl01.larc.nasa.gov/*` but that does not follow the links, it just downloads the shortcut as a file.

## Question

What should I do instead?

Is there a way for wget to recursively traverse all symbolic links to get all the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method of acquiring data is possibly outdated. As of January 1, all DAACs including LARC and LARC_ASDC are moving to https. This should solve your recursion problem.

Please contact support@earthdata.nasa.gov they will help you get the data you require.